# When can I safely call send method on objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, coding-style

I know it is a good practice to call `public_send` instead of `send` on objects so as not to unintentionally call a private method. However, if I know that the methods I will be calling are public for sure, can I use send? I have written this code:

```
[:name, :artist, :album,].each do |attribute|
  define_method "#{attribute}s" do
    @songs.map { |song| song.public_send(attribute) }.uniq
  end
end
```

Would it be considered bad practice if I replace `public_send` with `send` here?

Comment: `send` it is aliased as `__send__` in web have many information about this. [link](http://deaddeadgood.com/2008/11/17/rubys-send-method/)

Comment: What about `@songs.map(&attribute).uniq`?

Comment: @Stefan, this is indeed the better version. Danke Dir :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Calling send is fine, it's inside your class.

**Full Explanation**

Alex, Here is what I have always thought about this tactic. I believe that this is well inline with the community.

The [Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) say this about send:

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified. You can use `__send__` if the name send clashes with an existing method in obj.

This is a public method accessible to anyone in the world. That means anyone using your code can call private functions whenever they want!

Thus... you shouldn't really think in terms of public and private functions as you would in other languages. I would argue you change your definitions a little bit.

> *Public:* Well-tested, robust, error-checked functions which are recommended for use by the world.
>
> *Private:* Helper functions which may accept invalid input and break things.

I don't have some big rationale for this, just an overall impression about how these concepts work in Ruby.

For your specific problem its important to remember that you are the one coding this up, and I assume that your code is within a class you created. In that case, I use `send` all the time! It's shorted than `public_send` and I know exactly what I'm calling!

You will want to document it well enough so that anyone coming behind you will know what to be careful of.

Comment: It's important to remember that send can be dangerous! Please read http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/security_rdoc.html#label-send for details.

Answer (score 5):

Always use `public_send` where possible and avoid `send` it reduces your surface area and is overall a better practice.

```
String.new.public_send("sleep") # error
```

```
String.new.send("sleep") # hangs
```

In the example above replacing `public_send` with `send` is fine, but what if stuff is refactored? Better establish a practice where you expose the least amount of long term risk.